# Reactnative codepush not checking updates when app is running in foreground

Tags: react-native, react-native-code-push

Code below works fine but expected scenario is when app is active and running in foreground, it suppose too check updated and show dialog, but it only checks when app is restarted..

I checked [official documentations](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20CodePush%20will%20check,experience%20for%20your%20end%20users.) of codepush, but nothing looks wrong here.. why its not checking updates when app is active in foreground?

```
const App = () => {
  let navigator;
  const [restartAllowed, setRestartAllowed] = useState(false);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(null);
  const [syncMessage, setSyncMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    LogBox.ignoreLogs([
      'ReactNativeFiberHostComponent', // TODO: Remove when fixed:react-native-scrollable-tab-view
      'VirtualizedLists should never be nested',
    ]);
    if (navigator) {
      setNavigator(navigator);
    }
    SplashScreen.hide();
    syncImmediate();
  }, [navigator]);

  const codePushDownloadDidProgress = (progress) => {
    setProgress(progress);
  };
  const codePushStatusDidChange = (syncStatus) => {
    switch (syncStatus) {
      case CodePush.SyncStatus.CHECKING_FOR_UPDATE:
        setProgress(true);
        setSyncMessage('CHECKING_FOR_UPDATE');
        break;
      case CodePush.SyncStatus.DOWNLOADING_PACKAGE:
        setProgress(true);
        setSyncMessage('DOWNLOADING_PACKAGE');
        break;
      case CodePush.SyncStatus.AWAITING_USER_ACTION:
        setProgress(true);
        setSyncMessage('AWAITING_USER_ACTION');
        break;
      case CodePush.SyncStatus.INSTALLING_UPDATE:
        setProgress(true);
        setSyncMessage('INSTALLING_UPDATE');
        break;
      case CodePush.SyncStatus.UP_TO_DATE:
        setProgress(false);
        setSyncMessage('UP_TO_DATE');
        break;
      case CodePush.SyncStatus.UPDATE_IGNORED:
        setProgress(false);
        setSyncMessage('UPDATE_IGNORED');
        break;
      case CodePush.SyncStatus.UPDATE_INSTALLED:
        setProgress(false);
        setSyncMessage('UPDATE_INSTALLED');
        break;
      case CodePush.SyncStatus.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        setProgress(false);
        setSyncMessage('UNKNOWN_ERROR');
        break;
    }
  };

  const syncImmediate = () => {
    console.log('synced');
    CodePush.sync(
      {
    checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME,
        installMode: CodePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE,
        updateDialog: {
          appendReleaseDescription: true,
          optionalUpdateMessage:
            'Updates here..',
          title: 'New Updates',
          optionalInstallButtonLabel: 'Yes',
          optionalIgnoreButtonLabel: 'No',
        },
      },
      codePushStatusDidChange,
      codePushDownloadDidProgress,
    );
  };
  return (
```

Comment: You have it defined as `codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME` and it seems to be checking when the app is resumed.

Comment: @windowsill how can i render a custom modal instead of the default dialog?

Comment: They expose an api for that, check the docs.